# JDBC Java, row column count mismatch

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, hsqldb

I keep getting this error

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: row column count mismatch
```

I don't have idea why Im getting this error Im trying to resolve this problem from about 1 hour.

Im getting this error while Im trying to add new record to database with one user gonna make.

```
if(ae.getActionCommand()=="Save")
        {
            stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES('" + t.getText() + "','" + t10.getText() + "','" + t2.getText() + "','" + t3.getText() + "','" + t8.getText() + "','" + t12.getText() + "','" + t11.getText()+"')" );
            dbClose();
            dbOpen();
```

Comment: You insert more or less values as your table has columns.

Comment: It's pretty unsave to use plain Strings in SQL statements, as the values might contain quotes and commas, breaking your SQL statement. To know what's going on you should save your SQL string into a temporary variable and print out this variable to get the actually executed SQL. Furthermore you should use a prepared statement and set the values using the JDBC API. And you should add the structure of your table as well otherwise giving a correct answer is close to impossible.

Comment: Thank you guys for help, I resolved the problem, I had ID Key when i deleted it everything goes fine

Answer (score 2):

Do not use insert in this form:

```
INSERT INTO TAB VALUES(1,2,'x')
```

but use **explicit column list** and **bind variables**:

```
INSERT INTO TAB (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES(?,?,?)
```

The problem you have is that the table has a different number of columns than defined in your `VALUES` clause.

The latter form of insert disables this problem as you explicitly defines what columns are inserted.  The insert remains valid event if the table structure is compatible upgraded (add column).